# Largest number with five 1's and five numeric operations

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

You have five 1's at your disposal, together with five arithmetic operations of your choice. However, as you only have five operations, you should choose them wisely.

> **Question:** What is the largest integer that you can generate this way?

Rules:

- Numbers can not be infinite. No dividing by 0.
- You cannot concatenate the 1's (i.e. you cannot use two 1's to make 11)
- You cannot use any other numbers in any other form: no Greek alternatives, no constants such as $e$ or $\pi$.
- Parentheses come for free; you may use as many as you like.
- You may use two or more operations in a row
- You may use any notation you would like. One solution below uses "Knuth's Up Arrow Notation". Each arrow uses one operation of the five allowed operations.

Examples:

```
  1+1+1+1++1 = 5

  ((1+1+1)↑↑(1+1)) = 27  <-- Uses Knuth's Up Arrow Notation

  (1+1)^((1+1+1)!) = 64

  ((1+1+1)!)^(1+1) = 81
```

I have posted [my solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/23034/4865) below, let's see if you can beat me!

Comment: Hmm, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) 3^^2=27.

Comment: @Sleafar I was using the wrong function in Wolfram when I posted my solution. Forgot to update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Is it required to use all five $1$'s and all five operations?

Comment: @JulianRosen I suppose not, but you can always add `+`'s to the beginning to get rid of the extras ops. The 1's might be slightly harder to hide.

Comment: @dberm22 Adding $!$s at the end is a better idea.

Comment: I was thinking something like $(((1+1+1)!)!)!$ is quite large, but only uses three $1$'s.

Comment: “You may use any notation you like”; okay, let `#_n` be a notation of mine for the *n*-th Knuth’s arrow operator. Then I can write a number as large as I wish using `(1+1+1)#_n(1+1)`.

Comment: I guess you should be more specific about what constitutes a mathematical operation and what does not. Is Knuth's double arrow operator a feasible operation? Is Knuth's triple arrow operator feasible? What about Knuth's quadruple arrow operator? The quintuple arrow operator? **Do you really want to limit the number of operators, or do you want to limit the number of symbols used for specifying the operators?**

Comment: @Gamow I guess number of symbols. Feel free to edit the question to make it more clear. I'm not sure how I would update the wording to specify that.

Comment: @dberm22: It is not easy to express this clearly in your question, without explicitly listing all the allowed operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You may use any notation you would like.

Browsing Wikipedia I found the [Steinhaus–Moser notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Moser_notation).

If all ones must be used we can start with:

```
(1+1+1)^(1+1)=9
```

With one operator left we can put the number in a circle:

⑨

According to Wikipedia already ② is too big to be displayed. If less than 5 ones can be used, we can make the number even larger.

**Update:**

Instead of a circle we can use any n-sided polygon to make the number arbitrarily large. See for example the definition of Moser's number in the article linked above.

Comment: Brilliant. Maybe change `1+1+1+1+1` to `((1+1+1)^(1+1))` ?

Comment: @dberm22 Thanks, luckily there are still enough UTF8 chars for this.

Comment: in the vein of my answer below, if you don't need to use all 1's:

circle(circle(circle(circle(1+1)))) would be stupidly stupidly insanely larger

Answer (score 1):

$$((1+1+1)^{(1+1)})! = 362,880 $$

or, `((1+1+1)^(1+1))!`

Uses 3 `+`, 1 `^`, and 1 `!`

Try it on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9!).

Comment: With only a single up arrow, shouldn't your value be 9! or 362880?

Comment: @JonTheMon not sure why Wolfram mislead me. Changed. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

Must I use all 1's?

$$(((1+1+1)!)!)! = 3!!! = 6!! = 720! = 2.601 × 10^{1746}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the same notation as [Graham's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham's_number) and assuming that we don't have to use all five ones:

$$g_{g_{g_{g_{g_{1}}}}} = Something Absurdly Large$$

Note that g<sub>g<sub>1</sub></sub> makes Graham's Number (g<sub>64</sub>) look absolutely infinitesimal.

This is much smaller, but uses all five ones:

$$g_{(1+1+1)^{(1+1)}}$$

---

In general,
$$g_n = 3\uparrow^{g_{n-1}}3$$
where
$$g_1 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$$

Answer (score 0):

S(1+1, (1+1+1)!) = S(2, 6) is a large number, it has not yet been computed but is known to be > 7.4 × 10^36534

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver#Exact_values_and_lower_bounds_for_some_S.28n.2C_m.29_and_.CE.A3.28n.2C_m.29)