# Smallest impossible positive integer with 5 ones and 5 operators

Tags: mathematics

Inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23033/largest-number-with-five-1s-and-five-numeric-operations):

What is the smallest positive integer that you **cannot** make with 5 ones and five operators?

Rules:

- You must use all five ones and all five operators
- Allowed operators are: +, -, *, /, ^, !, Knuth up-arrows. Each up-arrow counts as one operation.
- Concatenation is not allowed. e.g. you cannot use two 1s to make 11.
- You may use parentheses freely

Comment: By "smallest number", I assume you mean "smallest positive integer"?

Comment: By small would -1 be smaller than 0?

Comment: Is concatenating 1s to make 11 allowed? (It's prohibited in the linked question, but not mentioned here.)

Comment: Are you counting $\uparrow\uparrow$ as two operations, like in the linked question?

Comment: @user3294068 yes, I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: @f'' no, concatenating is prohibited

Comment: @JulianRosen yes, each up-arrow counts as one operation

Comment: Are you expecting a solution to this other than brute-force search?

Comment: I'm thinking it might be 10, but I don't really know how to prove it *cannot* be written like that.

Comment: I can't imagine this being answered any way except a brute force computer search, making it a boring puzzle.

Comment: I don't see the point in "*You must use all five ones and all five operators
*" seeing as if you wrap it up in bractets one can easily continue to multiply by 1 to get their desired result.

Answer (score 1):

> I could generate 0-9 but I'm stuck at 10:
> $0=1/1/1/1-1!$
> $1=1/1/1/1/1!$
> $2=1+1/1/1/1!$
> $3=1+1+1/1/1!$
> $4=1+1+1+1/1!$
> $5=1+1+1+1+1!$
> $6=(1+1+1)!/1/1$
> $7=(1+1+1)!+1/1$
> $8=(1+1+1)!+1+1$
> $9=(1+1+1)\uparrow(1+1!)$
> $10=...$
> $11=...$
> $12=(1+1+1)!*(1+1)$

Comment: Can you make 5 with just threes 1s and 3 operators?

Comment: Even disregarding the number of operators, since 5 is not a factorial, the last operation was a sum, product, difference, etc. But the two operands can only be 0, 1 or 2 (since there are up to 2 ones in each side), so this never yields 5. \* Assuming you meant *three ones*

Answer (score 1):

Sleafar got the right answer - 10 -  by forcing it. I got same by the following observation: in order to get numbers above 6 one have to make a group of (1+1+1) to get 3 to further operate with. as the remaining we have two "1" and 3 operations available. Among these 3 operations one should be reserved for connection to the first group. And to get number over 7 one must use + operator to get 2. That leads us to solve the problem having 3 and 2 and two remaining operators. Having these assumptions, 8 and 9 are possible to produce while 10 is not.
BTW : the max positive integer is ((1+1+1)↑(1+1))! = 9! = 362880

Comment: Because you are limited by 5 operators